# Flutter json data from http.get is returning old database values in App and Latest values in Browser

Tags: json, rest, flutter

```
    final String url = "https://stsrefiners.com/wp-content/plugins/calculator/templates/mobilefixedval.php";

List data;
void initState()
{
 super.initState();
 //this.getJsonData();


 Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (timer) {
     this.getJsonData();

});
```

}

```
Future<String> getJsonData() async
{

var response = await http.get(
  Uri.encodeFull(url),
  headers: {"Accept":"application/json"}
);

setState(() {

  var convertDataToJson = json.decode(response.body);
  data = convertDataToJson;
 print(data);
  _isLoading = true;
});
return "Success";
}
```

Data is fetched using the getJsonData Fucntion and in URL the data is fetched using the MYSQL database using mysqli method when I open the URL in browser it returns the latest values but when I fetch the data in application both in android and IOS it returns the old.
The data is not updating at run time

Comment: Don't use await. Instead you should add a callback, and inside the callback you will receive the updated results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing the same issue due to the Network cache setting in the browser.

**Workaround solution**

I added random URL query value in API call..

**For Example:**

my actual API URL

```
www.xyz.com?id=1
```

I changed this into

```
www.xyz.com?id=1&r=somerandomnumber (every call)
```